# Elastic Search Intersection Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I want to fetch common words of list of users sorted by total count.

example:
I have a index of words used by a user.

docs:

```
[
  {
    user_id: 1,
    word: 'food',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    user_id: 1,
    word: 'thor',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    user_id: 1,
    word: 'beer',
    count: 7
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    word: 'summer',
    count: 12
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    word: 'thor',
    count: 4
  },
  {
    user_id: 1,
    word: 'beer',
    count: 2
  },
  ..otheruserdetails..
]
```

input: `user_ids: [1, 2]`

desired output:

```
[
  {
    'word': 'beer',
    'total_count': 9
  },
  {
    'word': 'thor',
    'total_count': 5
  }
]
```

what I have so far:

1. fetch all docs using `user_id` in user_id list (bool should query)
2. process docs in app layer.

   - loop through each keyword

     - check if keyword is present for each user_id
     - if yes, find count
     - else, dispose and go to next keyword

However, this is not feasible because word docs are gonna grow huge and app layer won't keep-up. any way to move this to ES query?

Comment: LMK if "intersection" is not the right word for this keyword. I have been trying to search a solution for this in search engine using the word "intersection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I had to do:

I have referred to @Rakesh Chandru & @jaspreet chahal's answers' and came up with this. this query handles `intersection` and `sorting`.

Process:

- filter by user_ids
- group_by(terms aggs) on keyword (word in example),
- order by aggregating (sum) counts

```
{
    size: 0, // because we do not want result of filtered records
    query: {
        terms: { user_id: user_ids } // filter by user_ids
    },
    aggs: {
        group_by_keyword: {
            terms: {
                field: "keyword", // group by keyword
                min_doc_count: 2, // where count >= 2
                order: { agg_count: "desc" }, // order by count
                size
            },
            aggs: { 
                agg_count: {
                    sum: {
                        field: "count" // aggregating count
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [Value Count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html)

One can look at "Terms aggregation" as a "Group By".  Output will give a unique list of userIds, list of all words under user and finally count of each word

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 10, 
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "user_id": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "words": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "word.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "word_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "word.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index89",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gFRzr3ABAWOsYG7t2tpt",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 1,
          "word" : "thor",
          "count" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index89",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "flRzr3ABAWOsYG7t0dqI",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 1,
          "word" : "food",
          "count" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index89",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "f1Rzr3ABAWOsYG7t19ps",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 2,
          "word" : "thor",
          "count" : 4
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index89",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gVRzr3ABAWOsYG7t8NrR",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 1,
          "word" : "food",
          "count" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index89",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "glRzr3ABAWOsYG7t-Npj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 1,
          "word" : "thor",
          "count" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index89",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "g1Rzr3ABAWOsYG7t_9po",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 2,
          "word" : "thor",
          "count" : 4
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "users" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "words" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "food",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "word_count" : {
                  "value" : 2
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : "thor",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "word_count" : {
                  "value" : 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "words" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "thor",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "word_count" : {
                  "value" : 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregations along with filter for the user like below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "words_stats": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "user_id": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ]
        }
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "words": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "word.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_count": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results will be:

```
{
  "key" : "beer",
  "doc_count" : 2,
  "total_count" : {
    "value" : 9.0
  }
},
{
  "key" : "thor",
  "doc_count" : 2,
  "total_count" : {
    "value" : 5.0
  }
},
{
  "key" : "food",
  "doc_count" : 1,
  "total_count" : {
    "value" : 2.0
  }
},
{
  "key" : "summer",
  "doc_count" : 1,
  "total_count" : {
    "value" : 12.0
 }
}
```

Comment: I have used this as referal, as I want to check "intersection", I had to use `min_doc_count` to check check it exists in more than one user. and order on `total_count` to sort.